# Access custom module file directly using AJAX

Tags: module

I want to directly pass POST data to my .php file which is located in my module folder. I know this is security risk, but I'll try to fix that later.

I'm doing research on this subject - how to do it with out using any components, so please don't suggest me com_ajax.

**default.php**

```
//defined('_JEXEC') or die; 
<form method="post" name="form1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" value="1">value1</input>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" value="2">value2</input>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" value="3">value3</input>
</form>

<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){

   jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").on("change",function(){
    if(jQuery(this).is(":checked"))
    {
         var checkboxdata=[];

         jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){

                  if(jQuery(this).is(":checked"))
                            {
                            checkboxdata.push(jQuery(this).val());
                            }

                  })

         var data = checkboxdata;
         jQuery.ajax({
             url: '/modules/mod_test/respond.php',
             type: 'POST',
             async: true,
             cache: false,
             data: data,
             success:function(r){
                    alert(data); 
             }
         })
    }
})

});

</script
```

On every tick in checkbox - I get alerted by data (so far all good!).

**respond.php** (custom php file I want to have direct access - send POST data with ajax)

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

---

**UPDATE: [jamesgarrett]**

default.php

```
<form method="post" action="" name="form1" id="mycustomform">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" onclick="function1();" value="1"> Apple</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" onclick="function1();" value="2"> Pineapple</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" onclick="function1();" value="3"> Pen</input>
</form>
<div id="response"></div>

<script>
function function1() {
var data = jQuery("#mycustomform").serialize() + '&thisisajax=1';
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo JUri::current(); ?>", 
    type: "POST",
    data: data, 
    success: function(response){ 
        response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        if(response.success === true){
           jQuery('#response').html(response.data);
        } else {
            alert('error');
        }
    }
});
}
</script>
```

helper.php

```
<?php

$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$data = $jinput->post->get('checkboxList', [], 'array');
$ajax_test = $jinput->post->get('thisisajax', 0, 'int');

if($ajax_test){
$some_text = ['','Apple','Pineapple','Pen'];
$response = "";
foreach($data as $d){
    $response .= $some_text[$d] . " ";
}
echo new JResponseJson($response);
jexit();
}


class ModHelloWorldHelper
{
public static function getHello()
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete example for a module in 1 file, not bypassing Joomla, not using a component, running php function on async posted data, & running some js on the returned data (why not).

Use the testing only section to get your query working before dealing with your ajax request.

```
<?php 
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// toggle this variable in order to show the results of the db query for testing purposes
$production = 0;

$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$data = $jinput->post->get('checkboxList', [], 'array');
$ajax_test = $jinput->post->get('thisisajax', 0, 'int');

// = TESING ONLY ===================================================

if(!production){
    $data = [1,2,3];
    $ajax_test = 1;
}

// = END TESTING ONLY ===============================================

if($ajax_test){
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($db->quoteName('*'));
    $query->from($db->quoteName('#__custom_table'));
    $query->where($db->quoteName('custom_id') . ' IN (' . implode(",",$data) .')');
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();

    if(!production){
        echo "<pre>" . print_r($results,1) . "</pre>";
        die();
    }

    // PROCESS RESULTS HERE

    $response = 'xxx?';

    echo new JResponseJson($response);
    jexit();
}
?>
<form method="post" action="" name="form1" id="mycustomform">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" onclick="function1();" value="1"> Apple</input><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" onclick="function1();" value="2"> Pineapple</input><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" onclick="function1();" value="3"> Pen</input>
</form>
<div id="response"></div>

<script>
function function1() {
    var data = jQuery("#mycustomform").serialize() + '&thisisajax=1';
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo JUri::current(); ?>", 
        type: "POST",
        data: data, 
        success: function(response){ 
            response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            if(response.success === true){
               jQuery('#response').html(response.data);
            } else {
                alert('error');
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very useful!
Is there some equivalent way to send ticked checkbox values to helper file (not by passing Joomla / hacking Joomla [ as long as it works ])? I want to put these values in special function and then fetch data based on checked values (if there are some)

Comment: You can move the php from the top of the code provided into a helper file if you already have your module set up that way.  Any part of your module that runs as part of the joomla request-response can take the ajaxed values from the jinput object, echo a suitable response and then exit before proceeding to the html output.  The helper file is no different in this regard.

Comment: 1. my recommendation is that you delete your helper.php file and your default.php file and keep the whole module in 1 file.  If your module is called mod_test then just have 1 php file called mod_test.php. This will make things much easier for everyone trying to help. 2. I have edited the answer to show where I would put a call to the database.

Comment: Well, I'll take under consideration your suggestions. Also, I do not see edited post version of yours. :/

Comment: Sorry. I was editing obviously while you were reading it.

Comment: Thanks alot! Quick few questions. 1) How can I see $result data or $query->__toString()? When I do var_dump, they do not appear. I get a "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" error, but I cant debug it as I cant find the way of checking each variables value.

Comment: I have update my answer with some code for testing the query out.  It's best to test and debug the php with a regular request rather than trying to see php errors through an ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

Tested your code and it works for me.

The things I changed were as follows, in case these are the issue:

- Changed all references from `$` to `jQuery` so that I don't have to worry about defining the jQuery object or any conflicts.
- Added `<script>` tags around your javascript (though I assume you have just removed these for the sake of simplifying your question's code)
- My test site was in a subfolder, so I had to update the AJAX call appropriately, so that it would load from the root.

If you go directly to the response.php URL in a browser, it should display "Array()". Is this the case?

As far as not suggesting com_ajax - that is going to be the right place to at least study to see how Joomla have built an ajax component.  Once you break out of the framework, you aren't really building a Joomla site.

**Update:**

```
Array(
   [3] => 
)
```

Means that you have run print_r() on a string and not an array, and so that alert is exactly how it should be.

```
var data = jQuery(this).val();
```

is only sending the value of the box you have just checked - not the form data, not the name/value pair of the checkbox, just the value - the `this` at this point refers to the element you have just clicked on (ie the specific checkbox) and not the data of the whole form.

For the sake of a quick, hacky example (this is not a gread approach), replace `var data = jQuery(this).val()`; with the following, which will send an array of checkbox data.

```
  var checkboxdata=[];


  jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){

          if(jQuery(this).is(":checked"))
                    {
                    checkboxdata.push(jQuery(this).val());
                    }

          })

   var data=  checkboxdata;
```

**Update 2**

You need to read up on how AJAX works.

Each time you call a page via AJAX, it basically acts the same as if you submitted a form whose `action` points to that page (or loaded a page passing parameters in the URL).  The only real difference is that the output is sent to your javascript function rather than printed on screen to the user.

Each time you call a page via AJAX, it is like re-submitting a form, or re-loading a page.  As with re-submitting a form, it is not going to remember what has happened to it before unless you specifically code it to do so.

Comment: I updated my code in original post (added $ to jQuery). Seems like script works the same, but array is still null, when I print it out.

1) What did you mean by "update the AJAX call appropriately, so that it would load from the root". How is this done? You can see my path also in edit.

2) If I go http://joomla.dev/modules/mod_test/respond.php I get Array ( ); Same thing - array is empty. I really want to make sure that I fill up the array using ajax.

Comment: The array path issue doesn't look relevent to you, as your site isn't in a sub-folder.  I just meant that for me, I had to load from '/subfolder/modules/mod_test/respond.php'.

Comment: Are you testing the array response with alert(r); instead of alert(data)?

Comment: Going directly to the URL should return an empty one, as it hasn't been posted any data and there is no code to remember previous requests of the page.  Have you tried building this outside of Joomla to make sure it isn't just some misunderstanding of how AJAX works?  I can't actually see it being a Joomla issue.

Comment: Well, alert data gives me correct response, problem is, shouldn't that data - which was just shown in alert, go as a POST to respond.php? If so, then print_r($_POST) should give the same result as alert did, but instead, $_POST is empty. I updated original post. Take a look, please.

Comment: @JohnCoolGuy1996 - your code as is, isn't doing anything with the response data of $_POST, so actually you are making wrong conclusions. How are you testing what the response.php is sending back? Note that you won't be able to see anything by accessing the response.php - don't expect to see anything from the print_r($_POST) this way - as when you do reach it directly there is no $_POST data.

Comment: Updated my answer - the problem seems to be you not understanding elements of JQuery, AJAX or print_r - it's not a Joomla issue.

Comment: @RichardB I updated once again. I still can't wrap my head around what is the correct way of getting POSTED data (checkbox values) and use them in simple function (for selecting data) from the same respond.php or helper.php. Maybe it's too much of a sleepless nights. Thank you for the effort tho.

Comment: Updated, but I suggest you go back to basics and learn first how forms work and then how AJAX works.  The correct way in Joomla is ultimately com_ajax, but I suggest you take your script completely out of Joomla until you understand the theory in a simpler example.