# com_Ajax - send POST Request

Tags: ajax

I am new to JavaScript. I'm creating my module. I'm trying to send data from an html form. I Can not use com_ajax...I create new class in `helper.php`.

```
public static function getAjax() {

    jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
    $input  = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mymodulename');
    $params = new JRegistry();
    $params->loadString($module->params);
}
```

I need to send  data to `default.php`.

I wrote a script to send data to a `mod_name.php`.
JS HERE:

```
<script>
 jQuery.noConflict();
   function function1() {
    var data = jQuery("lol").serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "index.php?option=com_ajax&module=auction&method=post&format=json", 
        type: "POST",
        data: data, 
        success: function(data){ 
            alert(data); 
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

FOR

```
<form method="post" action="this.form.submit();" name="form1" id="lol">
    <input type="text" name="price" onclick="function1();">
</form>
```

Did I do the right thing? And how can I get data in `default.php`?

Comment: why you can't use com_ajax? Same time your ajax call is to com_ajax...

Comment: Your PHP function name is `getAjax`. The method in the URL needs to be the function name but without `Ajax`, so in your case, it should be `method=get`

Comment: Look at this answer for an example of ajax in a module without com_ajax: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/20578/access-custom-module-file-directly-using-ajax/20584#20584
Someone else wanted to do ajax in a module without using com_ajax a couple of months ago - is this a school exercise or something?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your url, the correct is:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "index.php?option=com_ajax&module=auction&method=FUNCTIONNAME&format=json", 
        type: "POST",
        data: data, 
        success: function(data){ 
            alert(data); 
        }
    });
```

in your case, the FUNCTIONNAME will be `get`.

And your function, in helper  of  module, must end with "Ajax". Ex.

```
public myFunctionAjax(){
  //Do something
}
```

in this case, url will be `index.php?option=com_ajax&module=MODULENAME&method=myFunction&format=json`.